# PC reboots to blank screen

Tags: windows-7, boot, display

I have Dell PC that I recently upgrade to win 10 (manually with disk, not via win 7 update) and it has an issue the was also with the win 7 -

When I restart my PC the monitor display blank screen with massage "no source found", but the pc looks like is on. Only when I hard shutdown (15 sec pressing) the PC and turning it back on it boot.

What can I do?

Comment: Nothing to do with the OSes as you found out eventually. Whatever is happening is hardware related and happens way before any OS is actually loaded. It seems to be a graphics card issue. If it's a desktop sometimes re-seating the card solves it.

Comment: @MichaelBay Yeah I thought that too. I recently remove an graphic card that made me problems. Do you thing it has something with that? What can I do?

Comment: How could I or anyone else know with so little or vague information? "Dell PC"? There are thousands of variants of several generations with entirely different hardware inside. Which card was remove and which is the new one? Are the new one within the specs of the PSU? Probably not but how can someone know?

Comment: Sorry, I trying to help a friend. I waiting for the spec and I update it. There is no replacement card. I took off the card and instead used the onboard GPU

Comment: That rules out insufficient power. It points to an issue with the motherboard itself and perhaps there's a BIOS/UEFI update addressing it.

Comment: Do you have an USB stick connected? It might try to boot from there.

Comment: @Aganju nope.. no USB stick. only the keyboard & mouse.